# Why is a simple product not added to the cart for the first time?

Tags: magento2

When the page is loaded, for special customers products are added to the cart

automatically, for a bundle products it works good, but for a simple product

only the product name is added in the first time after the first time it works

normally, can someone help?

```
$data = [

   'qty' => $products_count,

    'product' => $products_id,

    'bundle_option' => $selectionProds,

    'bundle_option_qty' => $selectionQty

     ];

     $this->_cart->addProduct($_product,$data);

     $this->_cart->save();
```

[image: after the first load]

Comment: added code that you have tried

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem will be solved when after adding the product to the cart the cart will be updated ,  I will write specifically when this is done

Comment: $this->_cart->addProduct($_product,$data);
                                    $this->_cart->save();
                                    $cartId = $this->_cart->getQuote()->getId();
                                    $quote = $this->_quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);
                                    $this->_quoteRepository->save($quote);
                                    $quote->collectTotals();

Comment: it works for me