# How to update a cart after adding a product to the cart using an observer?

Tags: magento2

How to update a cart after adding a product to the cart using an observer ?

Comment: what you want to update. Please  specify reason of update and which field you want to update?

Comment: here is the reason     https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/262302/why-is-a-simple-product-not-added-to-the-cart-for-the-first-time?noredirect=1#comment370454_262302

Comment: where you have using this code `$data = [

   'qty' => $products_count,

    'product' => $products_id,

    'bundle_option' => $selectionProds,

    'bundle_option_qty' => $selectionQty

     ];

     $this->_cart->addProduct($_product,$data);

     $this->_cart->save();`

Comment: in my custom module

Comment: and it works when the main page is loaded

Comment: you have trying to add to cart /update  the cart qty on  page load?

Comment: AutoAddtocart/ProductAddtocart/Block/Addtocartauto.php this is path

Comment: yes,it's impossible ?

Comment: I want to update the cart  with event after adding to the cart

Comment: why you have calling `
AutoAddtocart/ProductAddtocart/Block/Addtocartauto.php`  on page load

Comment: what is the  buniness logic behind it

Comment: I am testing adding a product to the cart, then it will be a separate file where it will work with the cron  once a week

Comment: Please don't do add to cart from a block on page load.It creates the issue on Cache and Private content  https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching/private-content.html.

Comment: As you have want to build  your code cronjob,they why you  try with test script work like https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/39981/how-can-i-bootstrap-magento-2-in-a-test-php-script

Comment: This matters that it will work then when the customer logged into the account